# Azure Service Bus AMQP object receiver is aborted

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

When trying to add a message to an Azure Service Bus Queue, Sometimes I'm getting this error. Can anyone please explain why this happens?

[image]

The setup is, We have an Azure durable function that invokes an activity function. That activity function adds this message to the queue.

Here's how we do the queuing.

```
    public async Task SendWithDelayAsync<T>(T obj, TimeSpan delayProcessing, string sessionId = null) where T : BaseQueueMessage
    {
        string messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            message.SessionId = sessionId;
        }
        // Send the message to the queue.
        await _queueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, DateTime.Now.Add(delayProcessing));
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) , this happens when,

> An attempt is made to invoke an operation on an object that has
> already been closed, aborted, or disposed. In rare cases, the ambient
> transaction is already disposed.

Resolution is to Check the code and make sure it doesn't invoke operations on a disposed object.

I had similar issue in the past, may be try upgrading  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus SDK version to "4.1.2" if you are not using the same.

Comment: Hm.. Just checked and we already have the latest nugets. Also went through the code and we're not invoking a disposed object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try including this into your code. This would give you an idea whether the client is closed

```
if (_client.IsClosedOrClosing)
{
   _queueClient= new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);
}
```